# Downloading images from mobile phone

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, mobile-phone

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 and I was wondering if there's a way to download all images from my mobile phone, phone Nokia 7210. Is there a app that I could use? I'm connecting via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed tutorial on

[Ubuntu Forums -Hoary and Nokia Phones via Bluetooth](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=34740)

Another link from that.

[Send/Receive/Setup File Transfers to Bluetooth Phones using Gnome Scripts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=43843)

And Special guide to connect for your mobile 7210 (in different language)

[Nokia 7210 with Debian systems](http://guide.debianizzati.org/index.php/Debian_e_Nokia_7210:_uso_di_gnokii_e_gestione_degli_sms)